# How to position a Div vertically above another Div when in the code the Divs are in the opposite order

Tags: css

For a responsive design change I need to position an image vertically underneath the text instead of vertically on top of it. However I can not change the order of the HTML (note that the image is currently on top of the text when running the following example:

**HTML** (Also at http://jsfiddle.net/QjV4f/)

```
<div class="images">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Metro_wagon_81-720.jpg/200px-Metro_wagon_81-720.jpg">
</div>
<div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et nisl leo. Etiam ipsum libero, hendrerit sit amet mauris ut, condimentum commodo magna. Ut ac orci orci. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis arcu ante, vestibulum eu tortor non, imperdiet euismod libero.</p>
</div>
```

**This is what I'd like to achieve (this is a PNG attachment mockup):**
[image]

Comment: This may not be terribly helpful, but you can always change the order of your HTML working directly with the DOM in javascript.  Empty the children and re-append them in the order you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use `display: table-caption`, depending on your circumstances.

You would need to wrap `.images` and `.text` in some sort of containing element, which we give `display: table` and `caption-side: top`. Then add `display: table-caption` to your `.text` div and it should work like a charm.

This assumes that the faux table element does not have other issues, like not playing well with its siblings.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="images">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Metro_wagon_81-720.jpg/200px-Metro_wagon_81-720.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et nisl leo. Etiam ipsum libero, hendrerit sit amet mauris ut, condimentum commodo magna. Ut ac orci orci. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis arcu ante, vestibulum eu tortor non, imperdiet euismod libero.</p>
</div>

</div><!-- close wrap -->
```

CSS looks like this:

```
.wrap {
    display: table;
    caption-side: top;
}

.text { display: table-caption }
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eyesofjeremy/QjV4f/3/

This is based on [brilliance from Jeremy Keith](http://adactio.com/journal/4780/) and I've used it successfully for a live site. You'll need to enclose the CSS in the appropriate responsive media query, of course.

Comment: This is by far better than my solution :)

Comment: You can add a `width:100%` in `wrap` to make the content as long as the screen or another container.

Comment: Actually, I was assuming there might be multiple floated divs side by side. If it's filling the container that should not be a problem. But tables sometimes fail to play nice when floated, and making an element  `display: table` can sometimes lead to similar issues. Couldn't say off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to re-order HTML elements using CSS [which works in newer browsers which support flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), this includes iOS, Android and Windows Phone browsers (the usual targets for this kind of responsive design):

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
div.images {
    order: 2;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E4s76/)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the text left, and setting

```
width: 100%;
display: block;
```

and the image with float: none;

Maybe this helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried this here, but it doesn't seem to do anything: http://jsfiddle.net/nA6vV/

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

Use a tiny Css-WrapperClass and change its value to display:none; or "display:block;", if necessary.

```
.someImg
{
background:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Metro_wagon_81-720.jpg/200px-Metro_wagon_81-720.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);width:200px;height:150px

}

._imageNormal
{
display:block;
}

._imageMobile
{display:none;}


<div class="images top">
<div class="someImg _imageNormal"></div>
</div>
<div class="text center">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et nisl leo. Etiam ipsum libero, hendrerit sit amet mauris ut, condimentum commodo magna. Ut ac orci orci. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis arcu ante, vestibulum eu tortor non, imperdiet euismod libero.</p>
</div>
<div class="bottom someImg _imageMobile"></div>
```

It works as a switch for classes _imageNormal and _imageMobile.

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/kHk3B/

Comment: I don't understand... in your fiddle the image stills on top of the text. Anyway, I can't figure how display the image or not can help to change the position...

Comment: switch ._imageNormal to display:none and ._imageMobile to display:block in a media query. works well, but also like the table-caption-solution on top.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this solution makes you work a little: http://jsfiddle.net/QjV4f/2/

I float the image (to cause the flow break) and positioned it manually (in this case at `5em` to top).

Then, cause the flow break in the text (with `position:absolute`).

The problem with this, as you sure noticed, it's that it isn't an usefull solution if your text is dynamic.

But if the text have a fixed lenght, you could start adjust some mediaqueries to increment the margin-top in other resolutions.

You can use the "`float` / `margin-top`" trick as well as "`position:absolute` / `top:x`", both works.

Perhaps that's a little dirty solution... but without changing html or use javascript I can't think another.

Comment: You know, as I think about it, this COULD work, if the OP's images are all the same height. You would still need a wrapper, but you could do pos:rel on the wrapper with bottom padding equal to the image height, and pos:absolute on the IMAGE instead of the TEXT. A little less flexible though.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's better with a wrapper in the way you mention. Thanks, it's a pleasure have in the site people who cares for doing things right and wants to learn and help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what Vivek means is using the position attribute.   Is there a parent div above the .images and .text divs?  A container div of some sort?  If so you can set the parent to position:relative and .images and .text to position:absolute and then use css to position them.  Otherwise you can set the position:absolute to both divs and it will be absolute to its parent or to the body tag.

Comment: yes thats what i was saying its the first thing that we learn in css...so before posting a q at least the person shoud do some research...

Comment: fakeguy:  Check this fiddle out.  http://jsfiddle.net/jnLdk/  This uses the position attribute to push the image below the text.