# How can I stack paragraphs vertically inside of forced-square div using css (images provided)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a table in which I need to

1. Force the internal div to be square with a percentage height.
2. Include two paragraphs with one above the other.
3. Auto-size the font inside the paragraphs.
4. Ellipsize long text.

I have this working except for #2. I cannot get the paragraphs to stack.

I've looked at the solutions in several different questions including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211386/placing-one-text-above-another-text-html-css), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240814/how-to-position-a-div-vertically-above-another-div-when-in-the-code-the-divs-are), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482443/position-span-above-text-in-paragraph). No matter what I do I always get the paragraphs beside one another.
What I get:
[image: Not what I want]
What I want:
[image]
Please ignore the jankiness and sizing. I am no good with Paint and similar prograps. I need the title aligned with the top of the box with width 100% and the long text filling the remainder of the space below it, also with 100% width.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card-stack {
  width: 8%;
  height: 20vh;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.card-title {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  float: left;
}

.card-title p {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 1vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.card-text p {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  font-size: 1vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.card-text {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 67%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td id="opponent-deck" class="card-stack">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-title">
            <p>Title</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-text">
            <p>This is long text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="opponent-hand" class="hand" "></td>
      <td id="opponent-disc " class="card-stack "></td>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex-direction: column;` for class card.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card-stack {
  width: 8%;
  height: 20vh;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-direction: column; /* Added */
}

.card-title {
  /* clear: both; Removed */
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 33%; Removed */
  /* float: left; Removed */
}

.card-title p {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 1vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.card-text p {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  font-size: 1vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.card-text {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 67%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td id="opponent-deck" class="card-stack">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-title">
            <p>Title</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-text">
            <p>This is long text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="opponent-hand" class="hand" "></td>
      <td id="opponent-disc " class="card-stack "></td>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: That partially works except that the title expands outside of the box.

Comment: Live test version of just this issue: https://gingerslist.com/dev/temp/index2.html

Comment: Live test version of the entire page I'm in the process of building: https://gingerslist.com/dev/temp/index.html

Comment: It also looks different in chrome vs. edge. Chrome shows the two fields overlapping.

Comment: I was able to get it working using a table inside the div rather than multiple divs. I'll post it as an answer. Thanks for your help! It spurred my brain into a new direction.

Comment: Scratch that. It looks good at higher screen sizes but the lower td expands outside of the div when the screen is smaller.

Comment: The version using a table. It looks a lot better until the screen size shrinks: https://gingerslist.com/dev/temp/index3.html